# Django JWT Get User Info

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm using Django JWT authentication with the Django Rest Framework.
How can I get user info of the logged in user after I retrieve the token?

Comment: Try `request.user` it should work if you provided token with request.

Answer (score 7):

just check your app settings file, whether you have specified the jwt authentication backend or not.
if it mentioned there and if you are using User model ( in otherwords django.contrib.auth.models.User) `request.user` will work

If you are using your own custom User model

```
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework import exceptions
from rest_framework.authentication import get_authorization_header
import CustomUser # just import your model here
import jwt

class JWTAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request): # it will return user object
        try:
            token = get_authorization_header(request).decode('utf-8')
            if token is None or token == "null" or token.strip() == "":
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Authorization Header or Token is missing on Request Headers')
            print(token)
            decoded = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY)
            username = decoded['username']
            user_obj = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
        except jwt.ExpiredSignature :
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Token Expired, Please Login')
        except jwt.DecodeError :
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Token Modified by thirdparty')
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid Token')
        except Exception as e:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(e)
        return (user_obj, None)

    def get_user(self, userid):
        try:
            return CustomUser.objects.get(pk=userid)
        except Exception as e:
            return None
```

and add the following settings in your app

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'path_to_custom_authentication_backend',
        ....
    )
}
```

now in each view/viewset you can access the user object with `request.user`

Answer (score 3):

By reading the documentation on [DRF Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/) and as @neverwalkaloner mentions in his comment, we see that we can access the logged-in user's `django.contrib.auth.User` instance in a view, by using the `request.user` attribute.

Reading the documentations of both the recommended JWT modules for DRF:

- https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt
- https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I didn't find any evidence that they change/override the method of accesing the logged in user's instance info.

Answer (score 3):

If you are familiar with django rest jwt, you may see a config like this in your settings.py:

```
JWT_AUTH = {
 .....
'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',

'JWT_SECRET_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
....
}
```

You can simply create a method for example `my_custom_jwt_response_payload_handler` like below and address `JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER` to new handler:

```
def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):

return {
    'token': token,
    'user': {
        'username': user.username, 'id': user.id,
        ...
    }
}
```

You can add any data that you want in this response. then patch settings.py with your new handler:

```
JWT_AUTH = {
 .....
'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'localtion-to-my-own-handler-file.my_custom_jwt_response_payload_handler',
....
}
```

For better understanding i suggest read original source and comments for `jwt_response_payload_handler` in [here](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/utils.py)

Answer (score 0):

Once you logged in, means you are authenticated by Django, now you can retrieve current user details anywhere in the code.

**request.user**

request contains all the details of the User Model once the user gets authenticated. otherwise, it will show the Anonymus user.